# Google Sheets Formula to merge cells

Tags: google-sheets, merge, cell, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to merge two cells together conditional from a third cell result?

I'm trying to merge two cells together when a third cell shows a particular word.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to give an example. :)

Comment: not possible without script